# How to use TouchableComponent prop in react native element button?

Tags: react-native, button, expo, react-native-elements

Im trying to achive a ripple effect inside a RNE button that has `backgroundColor:` set to `'transparent'` because it is ontop of an Image. I am trying to implement the `Ripple('grey', false)` method from `TouchableNativeFeedback` to achive this effect with a different color other than transparent. I read in the RNE Button docs that it accepts a `TouchableComponent` prop where **I think** (hope) I can call the `Ripple()` method and indicate the color for it to use. But i haven't found any examples on the internet of how to do it nor can I imagine the syntax I should follow to use it... I would love for the solution to not affet IOS default touchable opacity when fixing this issue, that one does work fine in this case.. Please check the link for the documentation im basing myself on: [https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/button.html#touchablecomponent]

My attempt:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
        <Button
        type={'outline'}
          title="login"
          titleStyle={{color:'white'}}
          containerStyle={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            padding: 8,
          }}
          buttonStyle={{backgroundColor:'transparent', borderColor:'white'}}
          TouchableComponent={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple('red', false)}
        />
      </View>`
```

Error im getting:

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Versions: expo version 34.0.0, latest react native elements version.

Any help is appreciated.

Snack: https://snack.expo.io/@visfort/8cfad7

Answer (score 1):

This is almost a year old now but I myself have also struggled with this and eventually figured out a solution.

It looks like the `TouchableComponent` property accepts a string, function, or the component class. You can't pass a component itself. Because of this, you'll see that this will work:

```js
<Button
  TouchableComponent={TouchableNativeFeedback} />
```

However, you'll see that this raises an exception

```js
<Button
  TouchableComponent={<TouchableNativeFeedback />}
```

So now we come to the solution. The `TouchableComponent` does accept a function. This function must return jsx that can be rendered. When creating the function, `props` is passed down. These props contains the `.children` property which you can use to render the children inside any touchable component. Thus, you can do something like this which will give you a red ripple effect for example:

```js
<Button
  TouchableComponent={props => {
    return (
      <TouchableNativeFeedback background={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple("red")}>
        {props.children}
      </TouchableNativeFeedback>
    )
  }} />
```

Now, in my own project. I have created a helper function that can create this on the fly:

```js
function createTouchableFromColor(color) {
  return props => {
    // Here you can also add additional logic if needed, 
    // eg: you want to use TouchableOpacity for ios
    <TouchableNativeFeedback background={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple(color)}>
      {props.children}
    </TouchableNativeFeedback>
  }
}

export { createTouchableFromColor };
```

This way, you can just import the function and it makes it a lot easier:

```js
import { createTouchableFromColor } from "./*the location of the file*"

<Button
  TouchableComponent={createTouchableFromColor("red")} />
```

Comment: Viewed 1k times at the moment I'm wrtting this and no interactions yet. Don't understand why! Anyway, thx @Stalfos !